# Filereader JS API not reading files properly

Tags: javascript, csv, filereader

I have written the following code to read text from any csv or text file. However it sometimes reads successfully and stores in the variable and sometimes doesn't. Is there something missing in my code.

```
groupCsvData = [];
$('#add-group-upload').change(function() {
     var file = this.files[0];
     var reader = new FileReader();

     reader.onload = function(e) {
         var text = reader.result;
         groupCsvData = [text];
     };

     reader.readAsText(file);
)};
```

Comment: Reading the file is not something that happens immediately. If you check the result only from the "onload" callback, you'll get the content reliably.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that... didn't get you clearly..

Comment: It would help to be more specific if you would post more code. Where does your code examine the value of "groupCsvData"?

Comment: groupCsvData is just an array whose 1st element is what i want as the text content of file.. that's it! text is not getting stored in groupCsvData!

Comment: Well how do you *know* that the text isn't stored? What are you doing to test that? Have you tried adding `console.log(text)` in that "onload" callback?

Comment: yes i did.. i tried doing thorough testing and realized the upload event wasn't getting triggered.. finally resolved it.. thanx :)